# struts2: update second select based on first select value using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, struts2

I am working on a struts2 project where I have 3 html select controls each one being dependent on the previous selection. Say the first select is for country, second for state, third for city. The list of options in the state select would be filtered to only display the states in that country and so on. Due to some other limitations I am using the basic html select control instead of struts2's. Here is a sample of how I am currently populating the select:

```
<select id="stateSelect"  name="selectedState">
<s:iterator value="#session['myModel'].states" status="itr">
     <option value="<s:property value="code"/>">
      <s:property value="label"/>
</option>
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

I think that what I need to do is onchange event do an ajax call to retrieve the list of "states" based on the selected "country". The questions are:
1. how can I do this ajax call using jquery?
2. what do I need to pass as the url for the ajax call? just the action name?
3. how can I parse the results back? From java code I can return a list of "State" objects that have "code" and "label" and other properties. How can I parse this list in javascript and generate the proper options for the select tag?

Comment: I've done this before. I'd do what jonathan recommends use the struts2-json-plugin (it's pretty easy to use), actions which use it return a json string. If you use chrome, you'll see it right on the screen, with firefox you'll see it using firebug.  With json in hand you probably use jQuery's $.getJSON() the cat example on this page helped me a lot when starting: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/  You can copy it into your own page, and it will use json, and cat images off the flicker web site, letting you work with json without needing a server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select id="stateSelect"  name="selectedState" onchange="loadCities(this.value)">
<s:iterator value="#session['myModel'].states" status="itr">
     <option value="<s:property value="code"/>">
      <s:property value="label"/>
</option>
</s:iterator>
</select>

<select id="citySelect"  name="selectedCity" >
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
function loadCities(value){

        $("#citySelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
        $("#citySelect").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Loading cities", "-1"); 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MyStrutsActionToGetCities",
            data: "{stateID:" + value+ "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#citySelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
                $("#citySelect").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select city", "-1"); 

                $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                    $("#citySelect").get(0).options[$("#citySelect").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $("#citySelect").get(0).options.length = 0;
                alert("Failed to load cities");
            }
        });
}
```

Taken from [this tutorial](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/)

**Update**:This example is used to load city list based on the state selected. You can do similar thing to load state list on country selection. Also [here is a link](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/ajax.html) describing ajax request/response for struts without using any plugin

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the way to do this is using the [Struts2 JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) which ships with recent versions of Struts2.  To interact with jQuery in your JSP you'll want to use s:url to create a URL for your JSON action and then you can invoke it using jQuery's [.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or .load().

However, if your dropdown choices really aren't that complicated, don't over-architect. It can be easier to render them all using s:iterator on the initial page load and use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on your dropdown boxes to either move the data between select components, or augment the name attribute on one of the select boxes for the form submit.