# Problem while trying to update content on a jsp page using ajax in struts (when onChange event is fired)

Tags: ajax, struts2, dojo, drop-down-menu, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to update drop down lists when an onChange event is fired by change in selection of another drop down list.

I have 2 methods in mind:

1.) I tried using asynchronous calls using dojo, but in that case although I was able to call an action asynchronously but when the action is executed it does not update the contents of drop down lists.I guess I am missing some code which will refresh the contents of the drop downs.

Here are the codes:

The JSP page:

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-dojo-tags" prefix="sd" %>

<s:url id="scriptURL" action="getLists" /> 
<sd:a href="%{scriptURL}" listenTopics="getLists" formId="dayReport" showLoadingText="Working..."/>

<s:form action="viewDayReport" id="dayReport">
<s:select label="Customer " name="customer" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select" list="customerList" onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');"/>
<s:select label="Contact "  name="contact"  headerKey="0" headerValue="Select" list="contactList"  onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');"/>
<s:select label="Employee " name="employee" headerKey="0" headerValue="Select" list="employeeList" onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');"/>
<s:select label="Stage "    name="stage"    headerKey="0" headerValue="Select" list="stageList"    onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');"/>
<s:select label="Type "     name="type"     headerKey="0" headerValue="Select" list="typeList"     onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');"/>
<sd:datetimepicker label="Date" name="date" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"                             onchange="dojo.event.topic.publish('getLists');"/>
<s:submit value="View Report(s)"/>
</s:form>
```

The action:

```
The action sets all the 5 lists required in the <s:select> tags in the page.
The lists are getting generated properly, I have checked.
```

The struts config:

```
<struts>
<!-- Add your configuration elements here -->
<package name="Deutek.admin" extends="struts-default" >
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
    </result-types>
    <action name="dayReportPage" class="admin.dayReportAction">
        <result type="tiles">dayReport</result>
    </action>

    //This is the action mapping which maps the action in use.(Notice that the above action is also forwarding to the same page, it is the action which first time displays the page.)

    <action name="getLists" class="admin.getLists">
        <result type="tiles">dayReport</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

2.) The 2nd method I found by googling requires the following java scripting on the jsp page

```
function retrieveURL(url) 
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ 
// Non-IE browsers
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();       
            req.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
            try {
                 req.open("GET", url, true);
            } catch (e) {
                 alert(e);
            }
            req.send(null);
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE

             req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            if (req) {
                 req.onreadystatechange = processStateChange;
                 req.open("GET", url, true);
                 req.send();
             }
        }
  }
```

Here the "req.open" requires "url" as a parameter. Here I dont understand what should be the URL so that the action class I have mentioned in the first method gets called.

Please tell me what code am I missing in the first method for updating the drop down lists with the new lists which were set by the action class.

Also what should be the URL in the second method.

And which method is better in your opinion.

Please help asap.

Thanks!!

Comment: I hope I have provided all the required info. If I missed out please point out. Thanks!!

Comment: The struts2 dojo tags have been deprecated for some time now and should in general be avoided.  If you want to use ajax, this question covers all the bases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005056/struts2-update-second-select-based-on-first-select-value-using-javascript-and-jq

Comment: The answer I suggested is good because it divides concerns well. The struts2 community can address stuts2-json questions very easily.  The jquery community can answer jQuery-json questions very easily and in the end you'll get solutions faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I read the other thread you mentioned. I am trying to avoid using more frameworks because I am still new to struts and am using hibernate, dojo, tiles etc. and its getting really ugly and messy. I may get lost while trying to implement JSON also. Moreover I already have the normal action callings using struts config in place, so I might not get JSON right. I will give it a try in my next project.

Comment: Till then, if dojo is deprecated then how can I call my action class using the 2nd method I mentioned. Or for that matter I can use any way/method which uses my existing action class and action mappings in struts-config. Please advice. Thanks!!

Comment: You can have any number of actions pointing at the same class, you could have actions called "tiles-action","jsp-action", and "json-action" all of which have the same action class but differ in result types. Just add another action which uses the json result type. Then point chrome at the action, and see the result.  Ajax is pretty exciting, you can create actions that provide very specific services and you know you can call them from any page to get the data, you don't need to marshal everything you'll need for a jsp.

Comment: Thanks Quaternion.That sounds really great if don't have to change much and yet can implement JSON.

I have tried finding a good example but could not. Can you give me an example or a link to a good one or some concise material on JSON(concise cause I am running late on my project schedule).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to download struts2-showcase application from struts2 official site and extract it in your tomcat.
They have lots of example showing how various things working inside struts2 domain which includes your case like two interconnected combobox/dropdown

what you are looking can be found under ajax tab in showcase application

here is the link to download sample applications

[Showcase application](http://struts.apache.org/download.cgi#struts231-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: Thanks for your reply umesh!!
I will see the examples and get back in case of any issues.
Thanks!!