# Populate dependent dropdownlist based first dropdown using JQuery,ajax in struts2

Tags: jquery, struts2

I populate three dropdownlist, each independently to others when jsp page is loaded, data is taken from database by using struts2 tags only. But our requirement is that once the data is selected from first dropdown list then based on that remaining two dropdown list should be changed.plz provide sample code .

Comment: There are sooo many examples and posts available on this topic. You should have searched a bit. Anyway, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7010929/456135) is such a post

Answer (score 0):

This is not the place to provide sample code, all i can suggest that go for using JQuery/Dojo and if you ar every lazy Struts2 provides a plugin which integrate very well with JQuery.

[S2 Jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)

If you want to play arounf with Ajax, i suggest you to work with JSON, like when you select value from first drop down send that value to server and fetch the list based on the selected value, convert that value to JSON and let Jquery/dojo to parse that at UI.

Use Struts2 JSON plugin to make you life easy

[S2-json-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html)

In short SO community is always willing to help but it same time expect that you should show your efforts what you have done so far and what problem you are facing inplace of asking just for a code

Comment: Actually i am very new to struts2 as well as ajax so unable to decide which one plugin should i used. plz provide me suggestion, through which one i can achive my task easily.

Comment: @brajnandan: go with both the plugin i have mentioned in my post.JQuery plugin make it easy to create dependable drop down and JSON will help you make your response and request JSON enabled