# link between the two dropdown lists in jsp

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I have a problem at the 2 dropdown lists in my jsp 1- CLASS 2-SECTION.Both should come from database and if i select a class in the class dropdown list then the corresponding section values are came from the database. Please help by providing the code in jsp.And i am using mysql database
example:

classes  sections

class1    sec1_1
class1    sec1_2
class2    sec2_1

1. Suppose in the ***class dropdown list*** value "class1" is selected
2. Then the ***section dropdown list***  gets "sec1_1","sec1_2" values from the database

   - I am facing problem at step 2 please give me the code without using the jquery and ajax

Comment: Nice esoretic question. Provide us with code, examples or something please!

Comment: Do you want this functionality using ajax?

Comment: I don't think providing the JSP code will help you much! It'll just be two select lists which postback when one is selected.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7010929/456135)

Comment: sorry without using JQuery and ajax

Comment: What about plain javascript to submit a form onchange of first select? Are you ok with javascript?

Comment: please give me the code - No one is going to give you the code. You haven't shown any attempt to do it yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyPage.jsp

```
<s:select name="classId" id="class_select" value="classId" list="yourClassList" onchange="classChanged(this.value)"/>
<s:select id="sec_select" list="yourSecList"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
function classChanged(value){
  var url="getSectionsOfClass?classId="+value;
  window.location=url;
}
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="getSectionsOfClass" class="com.xx.action.GetSectionOfClass">
  <result name="success">MyPage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In `GetSectionOfClass` declare `classId` , `yourClassList` and `yourSecList`(with getter/setter) and populate the lists with your business logic. `yourClassList` will containd all the classes whereas `yourSecList` will contain sections based on `classId`.